# Clingo: create custom function

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am at wit's end as to create a "function" in clingo, if such can be defined.
In a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish, I wrote this very short program:

```
a(1..3).

adj(X,Y) :- a(X), a(Y), abs(X-Y)==1.

#hide a/1.
```

Basically, I want to define an adjacency function that given any two numbers will hold `true` if the absolute value of their difference equals one. What I'd expect from the above program is to output the results: `adj(1,2) adj(2,1) adj(2,3) adj(3,2)`, yet I am presented with this output:

```
Answer: 1

SATISFIABLE

Models       : 1
Time         : 0.000
  Prepare    : 0.000
  Prepro.    : 0.000
  Solving    : 0.000
```

(if I omit `#hide a/1.` it will output the answer: `a(1) a(2) a(3)`).

I feel like this is clingo 101, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the basics here. I'm trying to learn clingo by studying examples I stumble upon online but I'm kind of rushing through it since I have an assignment due tomorrow. If anyone could shed some light it'd be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It turns out the native `abs` function doesn't really work as I expected it to, but defining both conditions for the `adj` function does the disjunctive trick and works like a charm.
This:

```
a(1..3).

adj(X,Y) :- a(X), a(Y), X-Y==1.
adj(X,Y) :- a(X), a(Y), Y-X==1.

#hide a/1.
```

Outputs:

```
Answer: 1
adj(3,2) adj(2,1) adj(2,3) adj(1,2) 
SATISFIABLE

Models      : 1     
Time        : 0.000
  Prepare   : 0.000
  Prepro.   : 0.000
  Solving   : 0.000
```

Comment: Moreover, I was using the wrong (gringo) syntax for `abs`, which is `#abs`, or simply `|·|` in clingo. Hence `adj(X,Y) :- a(X), a(Y), |X-Y|==1` works just as well.